# Responsiveness depends on block size (not media)

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a block with moving border. When I move it - size of block changes. How can I make responsive design for block's content (e.g. `font-size` and inner blocks location) dependent on parent's block size?

Here is an example of block with ability to change size:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgkavh

Comment: can we see your attemps?

Comment: @Sfili_81 if I had an idea how to do that, I'd made it in provided example. I saw a lib that could do that but it based on js and I need to know is there an option to make it via css (or sass in my case)